# Find extrema in discrete $2D$ field

Tags: discrete-mathematics, partial-derivative

I have $2D$ height field (each point has a "height"). I have calculated partial derivatives $Dfx$ and $Dfy$ using convolution filter.

However, I am not sure, how to find local extrema based on this. Should I look for zero values in both derivatives?

Comment: vanishing derivatives will give you both extrema and saddle points. To decide between them you have to go to second derivatives as well

Comment: In a discrete setting, you may not see actual zeros in the "derivatives". You need to look for places where both $f_x$ and $f_y$ change signs.  That indicates a local extremum (an not a saddle point either, so there is no need for a second derivative - the sign change is enough).

Comment: @PaulSinclair I have found places, where $Dfx$ and $Dfy$ changes sign - eg. where discrete values in the neighborhood of the point are negative and positive in $y$ and $y$ direction. However, I am not sure if this is correct, since my max and min extrema seems to be swapped. For minima I use pattern: `- - x + +` (simplified to 1D case)

Comment: You need a pattern of $$\begin{array}{ccc}&+&\\-&\cdot&+\\&-&\end{array}$$ for a minimum, and its reverse for a maximum.